# Getting PrivateKey null X509Certificate2 c#

Tags: c#, x509certificate

> It is a console application and I'm using .net framework 4. 
>   When I try to get the private key from the certificate I get it as null any idea why is this happening?

```
string text = "some text"
SHA1 sha1 = SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
Byte[] textToBytes =  //ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(texto);
UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
Byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(textToBytes);
//Path to the certificate file.
string sFile = @"C:\myCer.cer";
//Get the bytes array.
byte[] byteCer = File.ReadAllBytes(sFile);
//Create the certificate with bytes and the password.    
X509Certificate2 myCert2 = new X509Certificate2(byteCer, "Password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

byte[] Encrypted = rsa1.Encrypt(hash, true);
string cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypted);
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)myCert2.PrivateKey;//I get the privateKey as null.
RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter RSAFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(RSA);
RSAFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
byte[] SignedHashValue = RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(hash);
```

Comment: ".cer" files usually contain public key certificates only. They don't contain the private key. Private keys are stored usually in .PFX/P12 files.

Answer (score 4):

Usually a file with the extension ".cer" is just the certificate, which is the public key and some associated metadata. A PFX/PKCS#12 file can also contain private keys.

You can check `myCert2.HasPrivateKey` to determine if any private key was loaded for the certificate. Since `myCert2.PrivateKey` should only return null when HasPrivateKey is `false`, I'm pretty sure you'll find that the system simply doesn't know about the private key to your certificate.

Comment: I'm seeing HasPrivateKey property set to true while the PrivateKey property is null. I'm currently using EphemeralKeySet attempting to figure out how to work around the lack of a user profile while also not importing the certificates to the server itself. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @masterwok Use `cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()`

Comment: thank you for responding! I've tried using that method and I get a private key. However, when I try to reassign the private key back to the X509Certificate2 PrivateKey property I receive a "Only asymmetric keys that implement ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm are supported" .. I'm using the flags Exportable AND EphemeralKeySet. I'm trying to get an X509Certificate2 instance with the private key populated. Am I going about this correctly by assigning the RSA private key back to the X509Certifiate2 PrivateKey property?

Comment: @masterwok No. you should not ever use the PrivateKey property (get or set) once on .NET Framework 4.6.2+ or .NET Core (any version), just use GetRSAPrivateKey (or whatever algorithm) and work with that result.

Comment: hmmm.. the API I'm working with requires the certificate(s) provided in an X509CertificateCollection. When the PrivateKey property is null after constructing the X509Certificate2 with EphemeralKeySet, using the certificate fails later down the line in SslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(). How does one use the cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() to get a valid certificate to add to the X509CertificateCollection? Sorry for so many questions, I've been scratching my head about this one for a few days now.

Comment: @masterwok SslStream doesn’t support EphemeralKeySet. (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24454). If you still have questions, please create a new question instead of commenting here.

Comment: and to anyone else experiencing the same issue, I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35663

Answer (score 3):

Currently this property supports only RSA or DSA keys, so it returns either an RSACryptoServiceProvider or a DSACryptoServiceProvider object. If no private key is associated with the certificate, it returns null.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_PrivateKey